# Extract Windows Phone 8 App from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've written an app with Visual Studio 2012 and the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and now I want this in one .xap data and transport this to my phone and test this. But how can I extract my source code to one xap-data and install it on my phone?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The WP8 project template gives you the option of debugging on real hardware.

Comment: If the device is plugged in, and registered as a developer device, I'd expect to see "Device" listed as a target for debugging.

Comment: I found it now, but there was no description of this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a successful build the .xap file will be in the bin/Debug or bin/Release folder of your project. You can then use Windows Phone Application Deployment tool to deploy it to a device.
This is described in detail [here (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
There are also simplier ways, also described in that article, like running aplication directly from VisualStudio.